# Can I put shade sail posts in a concrete footing in a barrel or should they go in the ground?

Tags: deck

We want to put our poles for a 16' x 16' shade sail in whiskey barrels that have been cut in half and fill the bottom with cement, then possibly add a layer of dirt for flowers or just decorative rocks.  Will this be enough to hold the sail?

Comment: How many whiskey barrels? Will the posts be structurally connected with other posts or do you plan to just attach the sail to the tips of the poles and call it a day?

Comment: two barrels for two corners with poles about 7ft tall, not attached to each other- house/facia for the other two corners

Comment: The barrel poles will probably fall over from the tension of the sail alone; no wind required.

Comment: that's what I'm afraid of...in ground seems the way to go but maybe put poles through barrels to be decorative

Comment: Decorative barrels sound fine. If the post is going to be 7 feet tall then you want at least 50% of the exposed height (3.5 feet) buried under the ground. I recommend a 12 foot post to make sure you can bury enough of it and then cut the tops to make them level with one-another. Make sure to also take your frost line into consideration so that your posts don't suffer frost-heaving. Per http://www.backyardcity.com/Shade-Sails/Shade-Sails-Installation.htm a shade sail will need about 150 pounds of tension to smooth out the wrinkles; above ground whiskey barrels with concrete stand zero chance.

Comment: Thank you for the info and the web site!